# Expression.Lambda can't convert types automatically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have some properties in many classes and want to compile getter/setter of them into lambda expressions so that I can use reflections with better performance.

(Profiled, and using Reflection's getValue/setValue takes up about 78% of total running time...)

However It seems that Expression.Lambda() Only supports one collection of parameter and will not convert parameter type automatically.

```
using Exp = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;
...
public class A { public int propA { get; set; } }
public class B { public int propB { get; set; } }
static Func<object, int> BuildFunc(Type type, string propName)
{
    var param = Exp.Parameter(prop.DeclaringType, "x");
    var exBody = Exp.Call(param, prop.GetGetMethod());
    return Exp.Lambda<Func<object, int>>(exBody, param).Compile();
}
...
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var fA = BuildFunc(typeof(A).GetProperty("propA"));
var fB = BuildFunc(typeof(B).GetProperty("propB"));
fA(a);
fB(b);
```

It will thorw an exception:

> ParameterExpression of type `__Main__+A` cannot be used for delegate parameter of type `System.Object`

If I change the expression into `Exp.Lambda<Func<A, int>>(...)` it will work with class A but will not work with class B.

If I use `Expression.Convert` to convert types, it will throw ArgumentException that tells me the method cannot invoke on instance of `System.Object`.

So what can I do to compile this expression just like below, which supports any type of object and corresponding method?

`lambda = (object obj, MethodInfo method, ...) => { method.Invoke(obj, ...) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better expression APIs available for invoking property getter/setter methods. You definitely don't have to resort to `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

The conversion from/to `object` is handled by `Expression.Convert`. You just need to plug it in the right spot.

Here is a getter/setter delegate compilation example where `T` is the type of your container (`A` or `B` in your example).

```
static Func<T, object> CompileGetter<T>(PropertyInfo property)
{
    // Target expression: (T obj) => (object)obj.Property;
    ParameterExpression objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    Expression body = Expression.Convert(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objParam, property), typeof(object));

    return Expression
        .Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, objParam)
        .Compile();
}

static Action<T, object> CompileSetter<T>(PropertyInfo property)
{
    // Target expression: (T obj, object value) => obj.Property = (TProperty)value;
    ParameterExpression objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    ParameterExpression valueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

    Expression body = Expression.Assign(
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objParam, property),
        Expression.Convert(valueParam, property.PropertyType)
    );

    return Expression
        .Lambda<Action<T, object>>(body, objParam, valueParam)
        .Compile();
}
```

Proof:

```
class Dummy
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

...

PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Dummy).GetProperty("Value");
Func<Dummy, object> getter = CompileGetter<Dummy>(prop);
Action<Dummy, object> setter = CompileSetter<Dummy>(prop);

Dummy d = new Dummy { Value = 123 };

Assert.AreEqual(123, getter(d));

setter(d, 321);

Assert.AreEqual(321, d.Value);
```

Please note: `LambdaExpression.Compile` is an extremely CPU-intensive operation, so once you create your getter/setter delegate, you must cache it in order to get that performance boost you're looking for.

Comment: *LambdaExpression.Compile* On newer .NET there is an optional parameter to "interpret" the Expression instead of really compiling it. If the Expression is used rarely you'll get better speed.

Comment: Is there a way that does not require compile time type specification for container class? It seems that I have to manually cache every classes that might be used in this way.

Comment: @Apliex-Ddr, of course. You can have your lambda getter and setter delegates typed as `Func<object, object>` and `Action<object, object>` respectively. This would require the introduction of an extra cast via `Expression.Convert(objParam, Type)`, where `Type` is the type of your container resolved at runtime. Then I suppose you can cache those delegates in a `Dictionary<PropertyInfo, Func<object, object>>` (and a similar cache for setters). This, however, wouldn't be my first choice for performance and API design reasons.

Comment: Nice it is what I want, thanks a lot.By the way, I also profiled it and the running time for two main procedures changes from (21ms, 6ms) to (18ms, 28ms) on dotnet core. However it brings a great optimization in Unity, changes the running time from (180ms, 400ms) to (60ms, 100ms). Anyway this is recently acceptable...

Comment: +1 Finally an example I understand ;-) the trick with which my problem was solved, was object and convert, instead of use a specific property type.